# linking between community faq page and faq page

Tags: feature-request, site-faq, meta-faq

There's a [community FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), a [main FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and a [meta FAQ page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) which I would prefer to have links to each other (two way) for the following reasons

- The [community FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) have data that compliment the two other pages well
- The [community FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) is hard to find. I didn't know it exists
  until I accidently stumbled upon it through links, and I think most
  of the others who found it probably found it by accident like me
- I believe many people don't know that the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag exists,
  and just asks questions that are duplicates of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)
  questions (at least I asked one of them before!) (please note that a link to [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) exists in the [main FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), but I think it doesn't exist in the [meta FAQ page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

EDIT: also mention the [main FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: As a new user I don't know such master FAQ page exists somewhere else. But yes the faq tag is already linked on \FAQ page. (in the last section: [What if I need more help?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about))

Comment: @hims056 thanks for pointing that out, editing to remove that suggestion

Comment: No more faq page (redirects to about page). :/

Comment: and this feature request cannot apply to the help center?